# Grok pattern optimisation in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Earlier I had only one type of log for an index, but recently I changed the logs pattern. Now my grok pattern looks like

```
 grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{DATA:created_timestamp},%{DATA:request_id},%{DATA:tenant},%{DATA:username},%{DATA:job_code},%{DATA:stepname},%{DATA:quartz_trigger_timestamp},%{DATA:execution_level},%{DATA:facility_name},%{DATA:channel_code},%{DATA:status},%{DATA:current_step_time_ms},%{DATA:total_time_ms},\'%{DATA:error_message}\',%{DATA:tenant_mode},%{GREEDYDATA:channel_src_code},\'%{GREEDYDATA:jobSpecificMetaData}\'" }

        match => { "message" => "%{DATA:created_timestamp},%{DATA:request_id},%{DATA:tenant},%{DATA:username},%{DATA:job_code},%{DATA:stepname},%{DATA:quartz_trigger_timestamp},%{DATA:execution_level},%{DATA:facility_name},%{DATA:channel_code},%{DATA:status},%{DATA:current_step_time_ms},%{DATA:total_time_ms},%{DATA:error_message},%{DATA:tenant_mode},%{GREEDYDATA:channel_src_code}" }
    }
```

and sample logs are

```
2023-01-11 15:16:20.932,edc71ada-62f5-46be-99a4-3c8b882a6ef0,geocommerce,null,UpdateInventoryTask,MQ_TO_EVENTHANDLER,Wed Jan 11 15:16:13 IST 2023,TENANT,null,AMAZON_URBAN_BASICS,SUCCESSFUL,5903,7932,'',LIVE,AMAZON_IN,'{"totalCITCount":0}'
2023-01-11 15:16:29.368,fedca039-e834-4393-bbaa-e1903c3c92e6,bellacasa,null,UpdateInventoryTask,MQ_TO_EVENTHANDLER,Wed Jan 11 15:16:03 IST 2023,TENANT,null,FLIPKART_SMART,SUCCESSFUL,24005,26368,'',LIVE,FLIPKART_SMART,'{"totalCITCount":0}'
2023-01-11 15:16:31.684,762b8b46-2d21-437b-83fc-a1cc40737c84,ishitaknitfab,null,UpdateInventoryTask,MQ_TO_EVENTHANDLER,Wed Jan 11 15:15:48 IST 2023,TENANT,null,FLIPKART_SMART,SUCCESSFUL,41442,43684,'',LIVE,FLIPKART_SMART,'{"totalCITCount":0}'
2023-01-11 15:15:58.739,1416f5f2-a67b-416a-8e38-6bd7de457f6a,kapiva,null,PickingReplanner,MQ_TO_JOBSERVICE,Wed Jan 11 15:15:56 IST 2023,FACILITY,Non Sellable Bengaluru Return,null,SUCCESSFUL,393,2739,Task completed successfully,LIVE,null
2023-01-11 15:15:58.743,1416f5f2-a67b-416a-8e38-6bd7de457f6a,kapiva,null,PickingReplanner,MQ_TO_JOBSERVICE,Wed Jan 11 15:15:56 IST 2023,FACILITY,Delhi Main,null,SUCCESSFUL,371,2743,Task completed successfully,LIVE,null
2023-01-11 15:15:58.744,1416f5f2-a67b-416a-8e38-6bd7de457f6a,kapiva,null,PickingReplanner,MQ_TO_JOBSERVICE,Wed Jan 11 15:15:56 IST 2023,FACILITY,Bengaluru D2C,null,SUCCESSFUL,388,2744,Task completed successfully,LIVE,null
```

Logstash has to process approximately 150000 events in 5 minutes for this index and approx. 400000 events for the other index.

Now whenever I try to change grok, the CPU usage of the logstash server reaches 100%.
I don't know how to optimize my grok.
can anyone help me is this?

Comment: switch from grok filter to dissect, it should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to improve grok would be to anchor the patterns. grok is slow when it fails to match, not when it matches. More details on how much anchoring matters can be found in [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/do-you-grok-grok) from Elastic.

The second step would be to define a custom pattern to use instead of DATA, such as

```
 pattern_definitions => { "NOTCOMMA" => "[^,]*" }
```

that will prevent DATA attempting to consume more than one field while failing to match.